# Ruby: Alias a method from a class

Tags: ruby, alias

Let's use Nokogiri as an example.

How can I rewrite

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
```

as

```
page = myparse(html)
```

I see the "alias" keyword but since it involves opening up whatever modules/classes a method belongs to, there is no universal way of aliasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a method in your application/class to wrap this for you:

```
def myparse(html)
  Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
end
```

Comment: You're right, that's not too bad.  I was wondering though about how to write a global method that does that for me, regardless of what modules/classes my method of interest lies inside.  I guess that might get messy quick though.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but keep methods out of the global scope.