# How to add an alias for attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, rabl

I want to add an alias for attribute `:phone` (under `@@address_attribute`), say `:phone_no`. How can I do it?

```
module Spree
  module Api
    module ApiHelpers
      ATTRIBUTES = [
        :product_attributes,
        :product_property_attributes,
        :variant_attributes,
        :image_attributes,
        :option_value_attributes,
        :order_attributes,
        :line_item_attributes,
        :option_type_attributes,
        :payment_attributes,
        :payment_method_attributes,
        :shipment_attributes,
        :taxonomy_attributes,
        :taxon_attributes,
        :inventory_unit_attributes,
        :return_authorization_attributes,
        :address_attributes,
        :country_attributes,
        :state_attributes,
        :adjustment_attributes,
        :inventory_unit_attributes,
        :return_authorization_attributes,
        :creditcard_attributes,
        :payment_source_attributes,
        :user_attributes,
        :property_attributes,
        :stock_location_attributes,
        :stock_movement_attributes,
        :stock_item_attributes
      ]
      mattr_reader *ATTRIBUTES
      def required_fields_for(model)
        required_fields = model._validators.select do |field, validations|
          validations.any? { |v| v.is_a?(ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator) }
        end.map(&:first) # get fields that are invalid
        # Permalinks presence is validated, but are really automatically generated
        # Therefore we shouldn't tell API clients that they MUST send one through
        required_fields.map!(&:to_s).delete("permalink")
        # Do not require slugs, either
        required_fields.delete("slug")
        required_fields
      end

      @@address_attributes = [
        :id, :firstname, :lastname, :full_name, :address1, :address2, :city,
        :zipcode, :phone, :company, :alternative_phone, :country_id, :state_id,
        :state_name, :state_text
      ]

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Alias a method from a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740379/ruby-alias-a-method-from-a-class)

Comment: -1 for posting such a long list. It is not necessary to write such a long list to show your point.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
def self.phone_attribute
  :phone
end

@@address_attributes = [
  :id, :firstname, :lastname, :full_name, :address1, :address2, :city,
  :zipcode, phone_attribute, :company, :alternative_phone, :country_id, :state_id,
  :state_name, :state_text
]
```

However, are you sure you should be using class variables here? I'd suggest this is better:

```
def self.phone_attribute
  :phone
end

def self.address_attributes
  @address_attributes ||= [
    :id, :firstname, :lastname, :full_name, :address1, :address2, :city,
    :zipcode, phone_attribute, :company, :alternative_phone, :country_id, :state_id,
    :state_name, :state_text
  ]
end
```

That uses a module instance variable and exposes it through a module method.

Comment: [link] (http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute). I was hoping to use alias_attribute.

Comment: I actually want the name to change in resulting json file. @ReggieB

Answer (score 0):

`alias_attribute` won't work for you because `:phone` isn't a proper attribute. It's just a key on the `address_attributes` hash, so what you're really asking to do is alias that key. Why do you want to do that?

If you want it to work, you need to define `:phone` as a true module attribute. Perhaps like so

```
module Spree
  module Api
    module ApiHelpers
      # ...
      module AddressAttributes
        attributes = [
          :id, :firstname, :lastname, :full_name, :address1, :address2, :city,
          :zipcode, :phone, :company, :alternative_phone, :country_id, :state_id,
          :state_name, :state_text
        ]

        mattr_accessor *attributes
        class << self
          alias_attribute :phone_no, :phone
        end
      end
      @@address_attributes = AddressAttributes
    end
  end
end

Spree::Api::ApiHelpers.address_attributes.phone_no #=> same as :phone
```

edit: needed to do the alias on the singleton class because they are class/module attributes